# How to set content in a Linear layout to the BOTTOM of the Screen in Android.?

Tags: android

See the following XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/calendar"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- <include layout="@layout/footer"/> -->

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/datename_bottom_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/upgrade_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/upgrade"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/upgrade"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/panchang_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/kalash_bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/panchang"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_range_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/timer_bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/timespan"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reminder_4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/reminder_bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/reminders"
                android:textSize="8sp" />
            <!--
         <TextView android:id="@+id/calendar_4" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_bottom"
         android:text="@string/calendar" android:textSize="8sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            -->
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What this looks like is on the left and what I want it to look like is on the right, I also tried it by replacing LinearLayout to RelativeLaout but still not working. Please Help.!
[image: Actual][image: Expected]

Comment: Use a `LinerLayout` as the root element and nest the `ScrollView` (plus an additional `LinearLayout`) in it. Then nest your _footer_ outside the `ScrollView`. That should do it.

Comment: you can use a relative layout and place it at the bottom

Comment: If the ScrollView is larger than the screen, do you want the LinearLayout to be at the bottom of the screen (like your right image) or at the bottom of the ScrollView?

Comment: I can not see your picture. what do you want to it looks like on the right

Comment: @user1455909 I want it like my Right Image.

Comment: Then try @Vyacheslav answer, I think that's what you want.

Comment: @PXDeveloper I have the same case , I want that linear layout at the bottom of scrollview if the scrollview goes larger than the screen, but i want it at the bottom of the screen if the scrollview is shorter than the screen, please help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use RelativeLayout, Look for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_panel">

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will give you something similar. Just place your widgets instead of my buttons.
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Very nice ans. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you just use `relative layout` as parent layout set the view as `alignparentbottom= true`.then if really need it you can put a `linear layout` in the remaining space

Answer (score 2):

You can include your `LinearLayout` into a `FrameLayout` and select in your `LinearLayout` the attribute `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <!--Your LinearLayout content-->

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try relative layout inside which you can add linear layout.

Comment: Is it possible to do through linear layout ? I don't want to use relative layout as a parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

set gravity:bottom to LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/calendar"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- <include layout="@layout/footer"/> -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/datename_bottom_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upgrade_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/upgrade"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/upgrade"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panchang_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/kalash_bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/panchang"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_range_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/timer_bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/timespan"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/reminder_bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/reminders"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
        <!--
     <TextView android:id="@+id/calendar_4" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_bottom"
     android:text="@string/calendar" android:textSize="8sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        -->
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```